# JavaScript regex match id in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I managed to get all the text with `.innerHTML`, code should match all IDs which have pattern: `sens[number]` Is it possible to get the number? Is there some way around? And please no jQuery, thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you tyring to do? get the elements from some ids in the innerHTML of some element? please be more clear, show what you have tried etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Preamble**

Don't try to look for elements from the `innerHTML` string. Strings are hard to parse, and the DOM makes it really easy to search for elements with specific properties. With that said:

**General Solution**

```
// grab all elements on the page and setup an array to store matches
var els = document.getElementByTagName('*').
    results = [];
// iterate over the elements
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  // see if the element has an id and, if so, if it matches
  // the "sens[number]" pattern
  if (els[i].id && /sens\[\d+\]/.test(els[i].id)){
    // found a match, add it to results
    results.push(els[i]);
  }
}
```

**Modern Solution**

Of course you can also use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and look for `[id^="sens["][id$="]"]`, but this can be problematic on older browsers (IE < 8).

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="sens["][id$="]"]'),
    results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  // all we've found are elements that start with "sens[" and
  // end with a "]". We still need to verify there's a number
  // between the brackets ([])
  if (/sens\[\d+\]/.test(els[i].id)){
    results.push(els[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply trying to get the elements that have a similar id

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="sens[number]"]');
```

^= will match any id starting with sens[number]
if number is supposed to be dynamic

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=sens]');
```

grabs all that start with sens or you could use a variable with the selector to get a specific ones with a number

```
var number = 1;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=sens"['+number+']"]');
```